# Check if a vector-space is closed or non-closed

Tags: real-analysis, vector-spaces, fourier-series

Let $V$ denote the subset of $C[-\pi,\pi]$ consisting of all finite linear combinations of functions

$1, \cos x, \cos 2x, ... \cos nx, ..., \sin x, \sin 2x, ... \sin n2, ... $

I want to examine if $C[-\pi,\pi[$ is closed in $V$.

From Fourier analysis it is known that for $x\in[-\pi,\pi]$ that

$\left|x^2 - \left( \frac{\pi}{3} + 4 \sum_{n=1}^N \frac{(-1)^2}{n^2} \cos nx \right) \right| \leq 4 \sum_{n=N+1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2}$

I want to use this result as a starting point.

My idea is that if I can find a sequence of functions in V that may or may not converge to a function that is (not) in V. Then I can tell whether V is (non)-closed.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess u meant to find $V$ is closed in $C[-\pi,\pi]$, if so then you are almost done.. Define $f_n(x) = \frac{\pi}{3}+4\sum_{n=1}^{N}\frac{(1)^2}{n^2}\cos nx$. Then we have $|x^2 - f_n(x)|\rightarrow 0$ for $x\in[-\pi, \pi]$. So we have $x^2 = \frac{\pi}{3}+4\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(1)^2}{n^2}\cos nx$ for $x\in[-\pi,\pi]$. So remembering orthogonality of $\cos mx$ and $\sin nx$ for $m\neq n$, we concluded, $x^2\notin V$. But that would imply $V$ is not closed.

Comment: Yes, thank you. So, V is not closed because the limit sequence 1/n^2 is not a linear combination of the functions in V ?

Comment: yes.. i forget to mention $\{1, \sin nx, \cos mx\}$ forms orthogonal basis of V. So if $x^2\in V$, it must have to be a finite combination of basis, which it clearly is not. So $x^2\notin V$